# How does C guarantee that the memory address equaling the array value will be available?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

```
char str[] = 'hello';
printf("%x, %x", str, &str)
```

In C the value of an array and the memory address of an array are the same.

How does C guarantee that the address will be available? 
What happens if it is taken?
What if there are two arrays with the same value?

Comment: Where does the assumption come from that C does give you this guarantee?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your premise is incorrect, and your question is based on a huge misunderstanding. Trying to fill in the gaps in your knowledge is likely to lead to prolonged open-ended discussion. See [Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: You're misunderstanding the term "value of an array".

Comment: "In C the value of an array and the memory address of an array are the same." is false. Hence, your question will change once you recheck that information.

Comment: BTW: Do you want `char str[] = "hello";`  `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: If one person is pointing to a car driver and another person is pointing to the car... it looks both people are pointing to the same thing. In your example `str` is converted to type "pointer to char", `&str` has type `pointer to array of 6 char`.

Comment: Better way to print pointers is `printf("%p, %p", (void*)str, (void*)&str)`. Please note the compiler warnings from your code: 'printf' : format string '%x' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'char *', same for argument 2.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding, expressed in this incorrect remark:

> In C the value of an array and the memory address of an array are the same.

The value of an array is a sequence of objects of its element type.  This is not remotely the same thing as its address.

The representation of such a value in memory is a contiguous sequence of representations of objects of the element type.  Such a representation has an address.  It follows from the form of that representation that its address is the same as the address of the first array element (at index 0).

You confusion likely arises from the fact that in almost every context where an array value or an lvalue designating an array can appear, it is *replaced* when evaluated by (some people say "decays to") a pointer to the array's first element.  That does not mean the array value and the pointer are the same thing.  Additionally, type-wise, the replacement is not the address of the array, but rather the address of an element.  This is a subtle but significant distinction.

That's pretty much all the language has to say about it.  It is up to implementations to provide conforming behavior, which they can do however they see fit.  In practice, implementations reserve space for arrays as part of the compilation and linking process (possibly including dynamic linking) or as part of the machine code for a function, and that *determines* what the address is.  In some cases, the address will be plugged in to an appropriate place or places in the binary (this is a key aspect of linking).  In other cases, the address will be stored in memory and read when necessary.  Or in some cases, the address may be held only in a CPU register for the entire lifetime of the array.  You don't need to care.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding or arrays is incomplete. An array's address is one of its fundamental attributes without which you cannot define an array. When you refer to an array in C without the `[]`, you simply tell the compiler that you're referring to the base address of the array - this is the memory address where the very first element (index 0) is stored. All other array elements follow this first element in a continous block of memory.

When you access an array slot, you simply tell the compiler to generate code that reads so many bytes (depending on the array's type) from the memory address *relative to the array's base address*. The slot that you specify is used to calculate the offset, relative to the base address.

The definition of an array (in the simplest terms) is just a set of bytes starting at *a particular memory address*. The type of the array is simply a hint to the compiler about the kind verifications it should generate as you retrieve values from the array slots. The language itself may impose more abstract rules on the array but most (not all) C-like languages that have arrays allocate the array the same way.

When you declare an array (statically), the compiler allocates space for it at an available spot - it's not possible (without compiler bugs or programmer mistake) to "put two arrays" in the same spot. If you have two array variables that are allocated at the same address, then you're accessing the same set of underlying bytes through both arrays. (If the two arrays have different types, you may not see the same *values* through the two arrays but the underlying bytes are still the same).

When you allocate an array dynamically (for example, using `malloc()`, the memory allocator will look for a suitable empty memory block where your array can be placed and it gives you back the memory address it has chosen. If a suitable memory block cannot be found (for example, your array is too big), you'll get an error in some form.

Comment: Hmmm " An array and its address are not two separate, distinguishable things - they're one and the same." I would say they differ `char a[42]; sizeof(a) != sizeof(&a)`

Comment: Fairly well put, but I take issue with "An array and its address are [...] one and the same."  They absolutely are not the same.  Maybe you meant to say that an array's address is one of its characteristic attributes, or something like that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is it better now?

Comment: @chux I'm not sure what you mean. In C, there are no objects. An array variable without an indexer is the array's base address.

Comment: "When you refer to an array in C without the [], you simply tell the compiler that you're referring to the base address of the array" does conflict with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923169/how-does-c-guarantee-that-the-memory-address-equaling-the-array-value-will-be-av/43923296?noredirect=1#comment74879696_43923296)

Comment: disagree with [In C, there are no objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923169/how-does-c-guarantee-that-the-memory-address-equaling-the-array-value-will-be-av/43923296?noredirect=1#comment74880195_43923296).  C specifies "object" "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values".  C11 3.15  Perhaps you are thinking of _object_ defined by some other language.

Comment: @chux That's true but an array is not an object in the sense as it would be in C# or Java or C++ - there's no array object with properties like Count, etc. When you refer to an array without an indexer, you're using it as a pointer and pointers just store addresses. The pointer has nothing to do with what's in an array slot. If you have a better way to explain it, I'm listening but I think my description is correct.

Comment: "When you refer to an array without an indexer, you're using it as a pointer"  Counter example: Try `char a[42]; printf("%u\n", (unsigned) sizeof a);`  Do you get 42 or a pointer size like 4 or 8?

Comment: @chux Then what about `*(a + 1) = 'x';`? I simply performed pointer arithmetic on the array variable and then dereferenced it. You get `42` for your example because of the semantics of `sizeof`, not because of the array: the compiler knows that `a` is more than just a pointer so it inserts the size of the static array.

Comment: @xxbbcc-- an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array in most expressions, as it does in your example in the above comment. "When you refer to an array in C without the `[]`,..." is not quite right; it depends on context. Also, the Standard talks of "array objects" to cover fixed-width arrays, VLAs, and contiguous memory regions allocated at runtime that can be accessed via array notation.